# Integer in place of Ids and Layouts

Tags: android, dialog

I have decompiled an apk for java code and in it I get these Integer values in the place of R.id and R.layouts. Can you explain why did it happen?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(2130903041);
    this.b1 = ((Button)findViewById(2131230721));
    this.b2 = ((Button)findViewById(2131230722));
    this.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
            Settingss.this.showDialog(1);
        }
    });
    this.b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
        {
            Settingss.this.showDialog(2);
        }
    });
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int paramInt)
{
    if (paramInt == 1)
    {
        final Dialog localDialog1 = new Dialog(this);
        localDialog1.setContentView(2130903043);
        localDialog1.setTitle("Set Message");
        final EditText localEditText = (EditText)localDialog1.findViewById(2131230724);
        Button localButton1 = (Button)localDialog1.findViewById(2131230721);
        ((Button)localDialog1.findViewById(2131230722)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

I know the first one  setContentView(2130903041) is for the R.layout.layoutname and the next two are the buttons in my layout so I replaced the integer values directly with the specific ids of buttons.

On clicking the SetMessage button in the layout a dialog pops up asking to set message. So I don't know how to set the id of that dialog box as it is not mentioned in the layout and pops up from nowhere.

The code I am confused is this:

```
final Dialog localDialog1 = new Dialog(this);
localDialog1.setContentView(2130903043);
localDialog1.setTitle("Set Message");
final EditText localEditText = (EditText)localDialog1.findViewById(2131230724);
Button localButton1 = (Button)localDialog1.findViewById(2131230721);

((Button)localDialog1.findViewById(2131230722)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to decompile the android source code. This is probably one reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simple. The IDs get converted to **Decimal** value in java file once you generate the apk. You have to convert it to **Hexadecimal** (you can do it using Calculator). Once you get the Hexadecimal value, just you need to search it inside **R.java** file, you will get the name of the field or id.

For example, in the line: localDialog1.setContentView(2130903043);

the id in Hexadecimal is 7F030003. Now you can search this value in your R.java file.

Comment: If the answer helped you, would you mind to mark it useful or upvote it? As by this any one is having the similar issue would get benefitted next time.